# EMGU.CV System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException while drawing contours (VectorOfVectorOfPoint) above a certain area in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, exception, emgucv

I'm trying to simply draw all contours above a certain area on an image.
After i get the frame and contours, I get the following exception while iterating the contorus:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: 'External component has
> thrown an exception.'

The code is the following (it is inside a timer):

```
' cyclic routine
Dim frame As New Emgu.CV.Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(1920, 1080)
Dim currFr As Emgu.CV.Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = videoCap.QueryFrame().ToImage(Of Bgr, Byte)

' copy frame
frame = currFr.Resize(1, CvEnum.Inter.Lanczos4)
Dim imgContours As New Image(Of Gray, Byte)(frame.Size)
If backgroundFrame Is Nothing Then

    ' save this frame as background for subtraction
    backgroundFrame = frame
Else

    ' background subtraction
    Dim elFrame As New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(frame.Size)
    elFrame = frame - backgroundFrame

    ' get contours from image (as VectorOfVectorOfPoint)
    imgContours = elFrame.Convert(Of Gray, Byte).ThresholdBinary(New Gray(80), New Gray(255))
    Dim contours As New Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint()
    Dim hier As New Mat()
    CvInvoke.FindContours(imgContours, contours, hier, CvEnum.RetrType.External, CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple)

    ' draw all contours on the original frame of blue
    CvInvoke.DrawContours(frame, contours, -1, New MCvScalar(255, 0, 0), 5)

    ' iterate through contours
    For j As Integer = 0 To contours.Length - 1

        ' if the current contour area is above a threshold
        If CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours(j)) > threshold Then   <-------- HERE I GET THE EXCEPTION

            ' draw the current contour of red
            CvInvoke.DrawContours(frame, contours, j, New MCvScalar(0, 0, 255), 5)
        End If
    Next
End If

' display the frame in the PictureBox
picFrame.Image = frame.ToBitmap
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work.
I don't know why, but the code needs to be changed from:

```
' iterate through contours
For j As Integer = 0 To contours.Length - 1

    ' if the current contour area is above a threshold
    If CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours(j)) > threshold Then
```

to:

```
' iterate through contours
Dim cont As Integer = contours.Size
For j As Integer = 0 To cont - 1

    Using cnt As Util.VectorOfPoint = contours(j)

        ' if the current contour area is above a threshold
        Dim area As Double = CvInvoke.ContourArea(cnt)
        If area > threshold Then
        
            ' draw the bounding box of the contour in red
            frame.Draw(CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(cnt), New Bgr(0, 0, 255), 5)
```